# What is the difference in properties java.runtime.version and java.version

Tags: java, system-properties

For logging purposes I'm getting the Java version written in log while Java program is running.

I found out that I can get the version with

```
System.getProperty("java.runtime.version") -> 1.8.0_202-b08
```

and

```
System.getProperty("java.version") -> 1.8.0_202
```

Result obviously is missing the "build" information in other but are there any other difference besides the result? Any certain cases when I should be using the first option rather than the second?

Comment: I’m not sure you can rely on `java.runtime.version` anymore, considering it is [not documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29).  I would avoid it altogether.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
System Property Name | System Property Content  | Where Displayed in java version Output
---------------------|--------------------------|---------------------------------------
java.version         | product version          | Line one displays the product version
---------------------|--------------------------|---------------------------------------
java.runtime.version | product version          | Line one displays the product version
                     | product build identifier | Line two displays the build identifier
```

From the [J2SE SDK/JRE Version String Naming Convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/versioning-naming-139433.html) documentation:

> - The content of the `java.runtime.version` system property can be expanded (beyond that of the java.version system property) to include the build id.

It seems that the property value can therefore be equal to the `java.runtime` content or differentiate by the *build id* as already pointed out in the question.

Anyway, as previously stated in [a comment to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399001/what-is-the-difference-in-properties-java-runtime-version-and-java-version#comment97518919_55399001), the `java.runtime.version` property doesn't appear among the currently documented [system properties](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29).

Answer (score 3):

`java.version` is a product version information of Java Runtime environment(JRE). JRE is an implementation of the Java Virtual Machine which actually executes Java programs.

`java.runtime.version` is a product version along with build identifier of JRE.

Answer (score 2):

One is JDK version, java.version and as the name suggest other is JRE version, R for the runtime

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think this might be a false assumption... As I run the app with only JRE (no JDK) both are working. I think fantaghirocco and Aniket Sahrawat are correct with their answer and the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) VGR linked supports this